# Where can I find helpful, up to date videos to learn how to tank raids for Cata?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to start raiding but I can't go in blind. I have tried to find some videos on my own of the Cataclysm raids. Some are older from the PTR and some are not helpful, and there are a lot of them out there. I need to find videos for all raids including Firelands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TankSpot](http://www.tankspot.com) is a highly regarded source for tanking videos.

Also, check out the in-game Dungeon Journal to get a summary of the boss abilities called out in the videos.